# How to correctly use BackgroundWorker to update ListView? [c# .NET 3.5]

Tags: c#, listview, backgroundworker

I am trying to use a BackgroundWorker to gather some data for me and update a ListView in my form while i display a progress bar and allow for the gui to not be frozen.
I am getting a cross-thread error when i try to update my ListView using the BackgroundWorker. To overcome this, i populate a temporary ListView in the BackgroundWorker and assign it to the result and then use that from the *backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted* to populate my original ListView.

**#1: Is there a more elegant way to update/display my ListView without having to create another temporary ListView in the _RunWorkerCompleted?**

**#2: Is there a way to pass the original listview as an argument to the backgroundWorker?**

I appreciate any feedback on this.

Thanks in advance!

**Pseudo-Code**

```
// Original ListView in Form
ListView orginalListView = new ListView();

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ListView backgroundList = new ListView();
    foreach(var data in database)
    {
        listViewItem = data.value;
        backgroundList.Items.Add(listViewItem);
    }
    e.Result = backgroundList;
}


private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        // Can I avoid needing to create a temp LV ??
        ListView tempLV = new ListView();
        tempLV = (ListView)e.Result;


        foreach (ListViewItem item in tempLV.Items)
        {
            orginalListView .Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To update user interface in cross-thread, you need to Invoke a new
>   Delegate. Check this link here for information on Invoke:
>   [**Invoke**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Yes you can do that in an elegant way without the need of another temporary listview:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var data in database)
    {
        if (orginalListView.InvokeRequired)
        {
            orginalListView.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                listViewItem = data.value;
                orginalListView.Items.Add(listViewItem);
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            listViewItem = data.value;
            orginalListView.Items.Add(listViewItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps explain the invoke call a bit. Here's a relevant [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and for the description links! I can confirm that this method worked for me

Answer (score -1):

You will likely just need to lock the resource whilst the thread is accessing it.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var data in database)
    {
        listViewItem = data.value;
        String name = "orginalListView";

        lock (((ListView)this.Controls[name]))
        {
            //Update UI, invoked because on different thread.
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { ((ListView)this.Controls[name]).Items.Add(listViewItem); }));
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Why is mine ranked down whilst the other is ranked up for a very similar answer but more code?

Comment: I didn't down vote but my best guess is that you said you need to lock the resource but did not explain why. To my understanding, locking it would not be necessary, but I could certainly be wrong, I am no professional when it comes to threads.

Comment: thanks for your quick response! dont know why its ranked down.. @st3_121

Comment: I can't comment on whether a lock would be required in this case with a single background worker thread. However, in the programs I have written with multiple background worker threads, a lock is required in order to handle cross thread errors when multiple threads are trying to access a single resource. I think it was Failsal who didn't like my neater answer :D

Comment: @st3_121 I DOWNVOTED that. I cant comment if your solution is "neater" or not, but there is no need of a lock when you can simply do that with an `if` check. Secondly, you are looking in an array of `Controls` which is not required at all. I did not downvote it just for the fun of it since I lost 2 points as well for downvoting, but because your solution is complex than it actually should have been. Try to give better answers on SO rather than trying to be sarcastic! cheers :)

Comment: In my defense, I was writing my answer at the same time as yours and saw that you had submitted but as I had finished writing I decided to submit anyway. I chose this method because similarly to the person posting, I created an app that had multiple threads, multiple processes and progress bar and this solution helped me. I guess I will look more into the delegate function to determine whether or not I can clean up some of my own code. Thanks.